# Python- How that should be loop which repeat the code?

Tags: python, loops, bots, pyautogui

Hi I'm working on an Instagram bot, I want to put this part of the code into a constantly repeating loop.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/a")\
.click()
pyautogui.click(x=1063,y=748)
sleep(3)
pyautogui.click(x=1154, y=855)
sleep(3)
pyautogui.write("Woaw lookls like amazing.^^")
sleep(3)
pyautogui.press("enter")
sleep(4)
```

Comment: Please improve your question quality reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and always provide a [mcve]

Comment: Dude that's just dumb... whatever credentials you use will just get blocked almost instantly if you ran a bot that just did the same thing over and over in a constant loop. Like the answer below says put it in a while loop, just set the value to True or False so while False... then inthe loop you can determine when to change the varaibel to True, and voila a bad idea in motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to loop indefinitely then you can use.

```
i = 1
while i < 10:
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/a")\
  .click()
  pyautogui.click(x=1063,y=748)
  sleep(3)
  pyautogui.click(x=1154, y=855)
  sleep(3)
  pyautogui.write("Woaw lookls like amazing.^^")
  sleep(3)
  pyautogui.press("enter")
  sleep(4)
```

Though I would recommend only looping through this a set number of times and then re-running it if you need to.

If he insists on indefinitely then go:

```
i = False
while i != True:
```

This will create an infinate loop until

> i = True